# Zoom extension not working on certain machines

Tags: magento-1.9, zoom

The zoom feature on the page link shared below does not work in chrome and firefox on all machines.It works on some and doesnt work on others, however it is working in IE Edge on all machines.

http://webshowcase-india.com/demo/vaak/women-vaak/t-shirt-retro-white.html

I have tried to find errors in the console but there aren't any.

One of the cases is that the zoom feature does not work on machines which are running Kaspersky antivirus but works on others.

Can someone please help me out with this!

Comment: working fine for me

Comment: That is the funny part. It works on some machines and on others it doesnt. Are you using any antivirus software?

Comment: I am using linux

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your magento_root

and delete `var/cache` folder. and might be your problem is solve

Comment: I did that. But still no luck!